# What is this kind of question known as?

Tags: single-word-requests, questions

A question that's not exactly rhetorical but the answer IS implied.

for example; "am I annoying you?"

you're meant to say no, and they are aware that they are indeed annoying you.

Comment: So far as I'm concerned, this can be called a rhetorical question - depending on context, of course. A similar one where you can be pretty sure the context means it **is** a rhetorical question would be *"You don't like me much, do you?"*

Comment: I still think there can be a distinction between the two, although it is very subtle. In one the answer is implied and 'used' (your example), in the other the answer is implied but not used in the conversation. ah... it's hard to explain.

Comment: in one the rhetorical question is used to answer the question as well as ask it, in the other you are not providing an answer, you are hinting at one. ...that's closer anyway. see this is why I need to know what it's called.

Comment: Much depends on exactly how you choose to define [rhetorical question](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/rhe-torical-question). Most definitions include the component *no answer is expected*, but to be honest I think that is simplistic. The key point is that a "rhetorical" question is one "asked" *in order to make a statement* rather than to elicit an answer. IMHO it's irrelevant to what degree the "expected" answer is implied or explicitly provided - the point is *both* parties (asker and audience) know perfectly well what that answer must be.

Comment: A term like "rhetorical question" basically just says it's not a normal question. It doesn't say anything else, really, because _rhetorical_ doesn't have any fixed meaning, and it can be used as a label for anything strange. Many people feel that when they've labelled something, they've explained it.

Comment: By the way, there is a Pragmatics tag, which is underused and would be appropriate. This isn't grammar, or semantics, but pragmatics. If, by the way, you were interested in the details, [here](http://people.umass.edu/partee/MGU_2009/materials/MGU0911.pdf) are some lecture notes on the analysis of questions by Barbara Partee.

Comment: @John Lawler: I shied away from going that far, but of course one could say "rhetorical" in this context means no more than that the utterance was made for effect rather than in a spirit of genuine enquiry. Maybe we should class the priest's *"Do you take this woman to be your lawful wedded wife?"* as a "performative sentence/question" (or whatever you call such self-actualising utterances these days). But as you say, labelling things only gets you sp far.

Comment: @SirYakalot Please can you edit your question to supply some more examples? I don't see why I have to say "no" or why the other person expects it despite knowing that they are annoying.

Comment: I agree with @MattЭллен. While it is apparently a *rhetorical question* in the broader/ general sense, there's a specificity to it, and therefore, deserves a sub-classification of its own. More examples to show this specificity will be needed to make the point clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still a [rhetorical question](http://changingminds.org/techniques/questioning/rhetorical_questions.htm), but of a particular subtype.

There doesn't seem to be agreement on the what the subtypes are called, but [this site](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/speech/games-corpus/guidelines-question-function.php) (like [others](http://scholarworks.umass.edu/dissertations/AAI8219791/) I've seen) lists three types of rhetorical questions (RQ):

> 1. RQ/Agreement: includes agreements that take the form of a question
>      (A. "Do you want to do that then?" B. "*Sure, why not?*")
> 2. RQ/Point: includes questions that are uttered with the belief that an obvious point can be inferred by the addressee (A. "The conference room is empty if you want to take your phone call in there." B: "*Am I annoying you?*")
> 3. RQ/Backchannel: indicates only an interest on the initiators part for the addressee to continue speaking (A: "There is a faster way to do that, you know." B: "*You don't say?*")

While the reference notes that "in all cases, the rhetorical question is asked for the purposes of making a point rather than to obtain information," your rhetorical question is of subtype *rhetorical-point*.

Comment: As John comments, labeling isn't the same as explaining. And any labeling system is at risk of obscuring rather than illuminating - as soon as you choose your labels you've imposed an interpretative framework which might actually not be optimum. I might, for example, say that the two primary classes of rhetorical question are those used for polite effect, and those intended to dominate (I only said "might", so pls don't tear into that one! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Classifying and labeling aren't entirely useless, however. (Just ask Linnaeus.) The _intent_ clearly differs in each classification, and the distinction (or the attempt to make one) matters to the OP.

Comment: Yes, but the Linnaen system for animals is a quite remarkable success story (and it's had a *lot* of drastic changes since his day). And don't forget his plant and mineral systems are complete flops, probably largely for the reason I gave. IMHO the one you quote for rhetorical questions won't have legs, because 99% of all analysable usages will turn out to fall into the "point" subclass.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that this is a grammatical thing; it's more social I suppose. When you ask somebody if you are annoying them it is *not* supposed to be because you know that you are already and they are *not* supposed to just say "no". When I ask somebody if I am annoying them, it is because I feel it is *likely* that I am annoying them — only they are too polite to say so. I don't want to annoy anybody and I certainly don't want anybody to have to sit there and *endure* me out of politeness. Therefore, when I ask if I am being annoying I am looking for a honest answer because I'm not certain if I am and I do not wish to be.

If someone is being annoying, knows they are and asks if they're being annoying expecting to be told "no", well they're just being fake; to themselves as well as the other person involved. So, basically, the question isn't really supposed to be rhetorical at all — it's just supposed to be a question.

Comment: Hi Ron, welcome to ELU. You make some good points there - particularly by not focussing purely contexts where *you* would be likely to come out with OP's example. I don't like the word "fake" (generational thing, I guess), but it's good that you put that alternative possibility forward. In effect, if *you* asked the question it would probably be a genuine enquiry, but in another context (with a fake/rude/domineering questioner, perhaps), it could be rhetorical (the *real* answer is expected to be "Yes", even if the person might be afraid to actually say that).

Comment: That's right. This is not grammar; this is [Pragmatics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics).